# Disable location with significantChange enabled

Tags: ios, swift

I monitoring device position with significantChange, and all works fine, every change i update location on my webservice.

What's happen if the user turn off system location? is the significantChange called one more time, so i can set that user has disable the location?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:

Comment: but can AuthorizationChanges event relaunch my app?

Comment: If your app is force terminated then you won't be getting location updates anyway. If your app is suspended or terminated due to memory pressure then you should still get a call to this delegate method. It is pretty easy to try it. I can say that you won't get any location updates once location is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this in your `viewDidlaod()` to check the status of locations service.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
    case .NotDetermined, .Restricted, .Denied:
        print("No access")
    case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        print("Access")
     }
  } else {
    print("Last know location: \(location)" // retrieve this from the location you saved it. 
    // You could also then set some value on your sever to show that it has been turned off. 
    print("Location services are not enabled")
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your `didUpdateLocations` save the last location.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  let location = locations.last // save this in defaults or some way to revive at a later time.
}
```